# IIS - Multiple CGI/ FastCGI instances

Tags: php, fastcgi, iis-8

We have a wordpress site which is running under PHP version 5.3. We are using windows 2012 - IIS 8. (VPS )

-We upgraded PHP version from 5.3 to 5.6 few days back.

-After which we faced the issue ‘site hangs frequently. Regarding this when checked the task manager we noted that too many CGI/ FastCGI tasks were opened as in the screen shot - [task-manager.jpg](http://www.sierratec.com/downloads/task-manager.jpg).

-We upgraded wordpress and plugin versions to the latest and removed unwanted plugins. But still the issue exists. Our wordpress version is 4.6.1. We have attached the screenshot regarding the plugins used - [plugins-sierra-wp.png](http://www.sierratec.com/downloads/plugins-sierra-wp.png).

-We checked the settings as in http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis and everything was fine

-[The screen shot of the error](http://www.sierratec.com/downloads/error.jpg)

-[The existing fasi cgi setting](http://www.sierratec.com/downloads/ref-3.png)

-Then we switched back the PHP version to 5.3. Till now there is no issue (nearly about 7 days) and we are continuously checking on this.

Kindly suggest how to fix this

Thanks

Comment: We have similar issues on this and I am scratching my head on it, too

Comment: Any one find any solution on that issue? my total system is down and still not finding any solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223593/multiple-cgi-fastcgi-processes-open-on-iis-8-5